# How to intercept all Zend_DB_Adapter Errors?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using Zend DB Adapter class from Zend Framework in a non-zend web application (don't need the whole framework). I need to intercept/handle all DB exceptions to create a custom error page. By default in case of any errors the adapter shows its own plain page with error message like "PDO Exception...".
Is there a way to customize this error output without having "try...except" operators around every single database request?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you need the try/catch constrcut to achieve what you want
as zend hierarchically extends all exceptions to all sub-packages you can easily decide where to catch which exceptions. the followiung code will catch all exceptions which are somewhere in the package Zend_Db_Adapter.

```
try {

  // my code which may throw exceptions


} catch( Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e ) {


    echo '<h1 style="color: red;">Exception information</h1> <pre>';
    print_r($e);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

ie. here you can see [the methods available on any exception object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php).